# Extract substring in exact order

Tags: python, string, substring, match, bioinformatics

I have a string containing a sequence of three letter amino acid codes and RNA sequence. I want to extract the amino acid code in the exact order it appears in the string.

```
raw_seq = '''GGACUAGCGGAGGCUAGUCC
METGLNLYSGLYASNPHEARGASNGLNARGLYSTHRVAL
LYSCYSPHEASNCYSGLYLYSGLUGLYHISILEALALYS
ASNCYSARGALAPROARGLYSLYSGLYCYSTRPLYSCYS
GLYLYSGLUGLYHISGLNMETLYSASPCYSTHRGLUARG
GLNALAASN'''
ascodes = ['ALA','ARG','ASN','ASP','ASX','CYS','GLU','GLN','GLX','GLY','HIS','ILE','LEU','LYS','MET','PHE','PRO','SER','THR','TRP','TYR','VAL']
for amino in ascodes:
    if amino in raw_seq:
        print(amino)
```

My code returns the amino acid sequence in alphabetical order, which destroys all its biological functionality. I also tried regex, but I can't come up with a fitting pattern.

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: Also this looks like a homework assignment, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a trick but use `re.findall` with `str.join` to ensure the output is in the order of appearance in `raw_seq`:

```
import re

re.findall('|'.join(ascodes), raw_seq)
```

Output:

```
['MET',
 'GLN',
 'LYS',
 ...
 'ARG',
 'GLN',
 'ALA',
 'ASN']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all chars and check if the current char and the following 2 are contained in your list of amino acids.

```
for i in range(len(raw_seq)):
    amino = raw_seq[i:i+3]
    if amino in ascodes:
        print(amino)
```

Which gives following result:

> ['MET', 'GLN', 'LYS', 'GLY', 'ASN', 'PHE', 'ARG', 'ASN', 'GLN', 'ARG', 'GLY', 'LYS', 'THR', 'VAL', 'LYS', 'CYS', 'PHE', 'ASN', 'CYS', 'GLY', 'LYS', 'GLU', 'GLY', 'HIS', 'ILE', 'ALA', 'LYS', 'ASN', 'CYS', 'ARG', 'ALA', 'PRO', 'ARG', 'GLY', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'GLY', 'CYS', 'TRP', 'LYS', 'CYS', 'GLY', 'LYS', 'GLU', 'GLY', 'HIS', 'GLN', 'MET', 'LYS', 'ASP', 'CYS', 'THR', 'GLU', 'ARG', 'GLN', 'ALA', 'ASN']

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_seq = '''GGACUAGCGGAGGCUAGUCC
METGLNLYSGLYASNPHEARGASNGLNARGLYSTHRVAL
LYSCYSPHEASNCYSGLYLYSGLUGLYHISILEALALYS
ASNCYSARGALAPROARGLYSLYSGLYCYSTRPLYSCYS
GLYLYSGLUGLYHISGLNMETLYSASPCYSTHRGLUARG
GLNALAASN'''

ascodes = ['ALA','ARG','ASN','ASP','ASX','CYS','GLU','GLN','GLX','GLY','HIS','ILE','LEU','LYS','MET','PHE','PRO','SER','THR','TRP','TYR','VAL']

raw_seq = raw_seq.replace('\n','')

sep_set =[ raw_seq[i:i+3] for i in range(len(raw_seq)-2)] 

result =[i for i in sep_set if i in ascodes]
"""
output 

['MET', 'GLN', 'LYS', 'GLY', 'ASN', 'PHE', 'ARG', 'ASN', 'GLN', 'ARG', 'GLY', 'LYS', 'THR', 'VAL', 'LYS', 'CYS', 'PHE', 'ASN', 'CYS', 'GLY', 'LYS', 'GLU', 'GLY', 'HIS', 'ILE', 'ALA', 'LYS', 'ASN', 'CYS', 'ARG', 'ALA', 'PRO', 'ARG', 'GLY', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'GLY', 'CYS', 'TRP', 'LYS', 'CYS', 'GLY', 'LYS', 'GLU', 'GLY', 'HIS', 'GLN', 'MET', 'LYS', 'ASP', 'CYS', 'THR', 'GLU', 'ARG', 'GLN', 'ALA', 'ASN']

"""
```